# avoiding browser sorting array response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my function return array as following

```
"66": {
    "student": {
      "studentId": "61",
      }
    },
  "61": {
    "student": {
    "studentId": "61",
    }
}..... and so on
```

In browser console (Network section) when I am checking Response, I seeing order 66,61 ... and so on, but when I am seeing in Preview is coming as 61,66 ... (it sorting automatically)
and even my angular function is a receiving array in sort matter. I do not want this sorting, I looking for exactly same order which my REST function is returning.
How to avoid browser auto sorting .

Comment: You have an object, and there is no order in objects, so **no**, you can't sort it, and you can't avoid it being reordered.

Comment: @adeneo: is it possible to order it by student->studentId at javascript level

Comment: @fresher only if you have an array. Objects are unordered.

Comment: @adeneo is correct, you have to convert these objects into array if you want to sort them

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order